# Sitefinity widgets not showing on News Detail page

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Inherited a Sitefinity website. There's a news list page, which I discovered is reused by the news detail pages to display content. If I update the list page, the changes are reflected on the detail pages.

*Sometimes.*

I have a content block that contains a "header" text - updating this in the list page is replicated across the details pages. Adding a javascript widget to the page to inject some custom javascript replicates across the details pages as well.

Adding a new content block or css widget **does not** replicate across the details pages.

Is there some rhyme or reason to this behavior that I'm missing?

---

My specifics:

I've successfully created widgets in the MVC several times now. I essentially need to add a new widget to just the news pages. Which seemed simple enough until I discovered that news pages are not individually created pages like... well, pages... but instead are just a content piece that is dynamically inserted in the news widget on the "parent" listing page. At least as far as I can tell that's how it appears to be working.

Adding my widget to the page didn't work, as I explained above. I then tried recreating it in the page itself using javascript, content block, and css widgets, at which time I discovered that the javascript is the only one making it to the details pages. I imagine this has to do with the way javascript widgets actually make it to the page - their placement is selected in advanced options, rather than simply appearing inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitefinity widgets go beyond presentation, and actually *control routing*.

As such content widgets (baseline or custom) have two 'modes' that they operate in: list and detail. Slugs for details are automatically generated in the following format.

```
/News
/News/{News-item-slug}
```

Of course, a list and a detail should look very different. To accommodate that, the widgets have *two separate configurable templates.*

So, add your custom html and javascript to the appropriate template to have it only apply in a given mode.

Comment: Don't suppose you have a link to some documentation on how to create the two-mode widget in sitefinity mvc?

Comment: Conveniently, the MVC side of Sitefinity is open source, so you can check out the NewsController in its entirety [here](https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.News/MVC/Controllers/NewsController.cs)